# WiX - passing parameter from MSI to Xeam bootstrapper application

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using a WiX bundle with Xeam Visual Installer as a bootstrapper UI application.

What I would like to do is set some variables inside the Custom Actions that my MSI is running, and I have figured out how to do that.  I can see in my logs that the variables are being set.

My problem is I hoped that I would be able to read these variable and display them on the last page of my bootstrapper UI.  Out here the variables still show as empty strings.

If you are familiar with Xeam, I am trying to access them like this:

```
MyProp = Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["MY_PROP"];
```

Similar to the way you read and set properties during the initial bootstrapper workflow, before everything is sent to the MSI.

Has anyone else tried to do this.  Should it be possible or are there any other solutions you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently not possible.  The solution is to use the registry instead.